# Allow a div to only grow vertically for x amount of pixels then show scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So, basically if a div reaches 50px I want to, then, turn on the scroll bar (vertcially). Any JQuery Ideas would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that in CSS, though max-height may require hacks for IE.

```
div {
    max-height: 50px;
    clip: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

If you have a specific jQuery use, you would need to share a little code.

Comment: better answer than mine. I was thinking jquery.

Comment: @aepheus - Well, jQuery could be an appropriate solution too, depending on the situation. Might be easier than messing with IE CSS fixes.

Comment: @Douglas - Thanks for the note. Wasn't sure about IE7.

Answer (score 1):

When adding content to the div, check $('#something').height(). If it exceeds 50, set height to 50, and add scroll bars, otherwise leave it alone.

$('#something').css('height','50px').css('overflow','auto');